# Magento get language code in template file

Tags: php, magento

I need a helper function to get the current language code. I want to use it in a templete file, like /products/view.phtml, only for testing purposes.

Does it already exist?

I have something in mind like the URL-helper

```
$url = $this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can get the current locale code this way :

```
$locale = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode();
```

Comment: With that one you get the locale currently used in translate model, but both are technically correct.

Comment: How would we get the LocaleName? (like we see in backend in the dropdown when we set the locale)

Answer (score 14):

Result for answers given in this topic for "Belgium:French" (Be_Fr):

- `strtolower(Mage::getStoreConfig('general/country/default'));` =  `be`
- `substr(Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code'),0,2);` = `fr`
- `Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode();` = `fr_BE`

Note that

`Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode()` == `Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code')`

but with the second one, you can specify an other store than default one (`Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code', $storeId)`), so I would recommand it.

Answer (score 9):

Afaik there is no such helper function, but you could of course build your own using:

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$_language_code = substr(Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code', $_store->getId()),0,2);
```

where $_store is current store object

Comment: This is just what I needed. Tnx

Answer (score 0):

You can also use :

$languageCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getLanguageCode();

**Don't forget to configure your store locales in your admin**. Go to menu :

System -> Configuration -> General -> Locale Options

And set the correct Locale for each Websites or stores

Answer (score -1):

For use in the html elements `lang` attribute etc.

```
echo strtolower(Mage::getStoreConfig('general/country/default')); // "en"
```