# Checking the TLD of a site using Javascript

Tags: javascript, magento, tld

A quick intro: I am building error pages for a Magento build. I need to identify the top-level-domain for a site so i can do some conditional statements to show different translations for each TLD of the site.

I need some javascript that will just return if the site is .co.uk / .fr / .es / .pt etc.

So that i can hide and show the correct languages are required.

Can anyone give me a hand ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why take this detour? Magento has pre-defined ways to get the current language: [Magento get language code in template file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6579287)

Comment: Because when you are working with error pages they are in the root directory.

Comment: Also for example if you are using report.phtml to style a page for when there is an error connecting to the database, wont this fail due to no databse connection?

Comment: Well, it boils down to the question whether `Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode();` is available in your context. I don't know whether it is because I don't know Magento that well, but it very well might

Answer (score 1):

Don't know why you need JS to do this thing.

Check the below JS code which will detect the domain extension. But if it is `.co.uk`, it will only say `uk`, but I think it should be OK to you as you only want to detect the country out of it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var extension=location.hostname.split(".");
extension=extension[extension.length-1];
alert(extension);
</script>
```

Comment: This wouldn't be ok, because for example portugal would be pt.com

Comment: @FrankClark portugal will be ".com.pt" and not "pt.com".. correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in your template:

```
<?php
$tld = strrchr ( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], "." );
$tld = substr ( $tld, 1 );
?>
```

Then use this inside the page to set the value in javascript:

```
<script>
var tld = <?php echo $tld; ?>;
</script>
```